# Best way to prevent Google from indexing a directory

Tags: seo, search-engine, robots.txt

I've researched many methods on how to prevent Google/other search engines from crawling a specific directory. The two most popular ones I've seen are:

1. Adding it into the robots.txt file: `Disallow: /directory/`
2. Adding a meta tag: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">`

Which method would work the best? I want this directory to remain "invisible" from search engines so it does not affect any of my site's ranking.

In other words, I want this directory to be neutral/invisible and "just there." I don't want it to affect any ranking. Which method would be the best to achieve this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO which is off-topic at Stack Overflow.


Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robots.txt is the way to go for this.

According to [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en), you only use the meta tag if you don't have rights to create/edit the robots.txt file.

Comment: Thanks! Also, by adding this to the robots.txt file, will it make the directory "invisible" to the search engine? Meaning will it not affect the ranking of the other pages on my site.

Comment: @user2154729 Nothing you put on the web is "invisible". But Google is expected to respect the `robots.txt` file and not download forbidden which, which then should not have any impact whatsoever on your other pages.

Comment: @janos Thanks! Lastly, do you think it's safe to just place a 404 or 403 error for the entire directory in my .htaccess file, according to the IP? This directory is mainly just for me and a few other people.

Comment: @user2154729 It's *safer* ;-) (than not having it)

Comment: @janos Only a few files in the directory will be available to the public, the rest of the files (including the main directory URL) will have either a 404 or a 403 error. Which one would be better for this case (404 or 403)? Keep in mind that I want to maintain the ranking of the rest of the pages on my site, so I don't want this 404 or 403 error affecting it.

Comment: 403 is more appropriate, as it means *Forbidden*. Google will not attempt to download files that are matched by your `robots.txt`, so it will not hit any 403 errors.

Comment: @janos So all in all, if I add a 403 error to the directory and only to a FEW files in the directory, will it affect the overall ranking of the other content on my website?

Comment: @user2154729 I don't think Google Bot will come from just one IP, it probably has many IPs - so don't try to hardcode what you see from them as their IP, because I'm guessing it could/will change.

Comment: @canhazbits I know, I'm doing it the other way around. Just allowing access to the directory and specific files from my IP.